# How do I delete space between loop output using python?

Tags: python, loops, space

```
def print_numbers2():
    for a in range(1,6):
        c = 5-a
        print("." * c , str(a) *a)
```

My output is

**.... 1**
**... 22**
**.. 333**
**. 4444**
**55555**

But output I was expecting to get was without space between dot(.) and number. There is space between dots and numbers.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Replace the ',' with a '+' in the print statement. That will concatenate the two strings directly together (as they are both strings, this doesn't work if that are not) without a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
def print_numbers2():
    for a in range(1,6):
        c = 5-a
        print("." * c +  str(a) *a)
```

**Output** :

```
>>> print_numbers2()
....1
...22
..333
.4444
55555
```

You need to join the output as a string in stead printing side by side as two different string.

Answer (score 3):

just set [`sep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to an empty string:

```py
def print_numbers2():
    for a in range(1,6):
        c = 5-a
        print("." * c , str(a) *a, sep='')
```

Answer (score 1):

use + instead of , in the print.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
def print_numbers2():
    for a in range(1,6):
        c = 5-a
        print("."*c,str(a)*a,sep='')
```

```
print_numbers2()
....1
...22
..333
.4444
55555
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Many methods already provided.

One more using fstrings :

```py
def print_numbers2():
    for a in range(1, 6):
        c = 5-a
        print(f"{'.' * c}{str(a) * a}")
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is replace comma with a plus sign in your print statement.
Like this,

```
print("." * c + str(a) *a)
```